# How do I create a quick test/demo app with ArcGIS Mobile

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-mobile

We are trying to do a quick evaluation of ArcGIS Mobile 10 on Windows.  Part of that is determining whether we can load online maps (like arcgisserveronline for example) and what the performance/rendering quality is like.  We tried using the 9.3 TileServices example but it does not appear to work with 10.0.  Anyone else tried anything like this?  Anyone know any good links on how to quickly get started on displaying maps on mobile (without our own map server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESRI answered this for me - MobileServiceConnection class is what you need to use.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also evaluating ArcGIS Mobile 10 for a large project.

In the "Mobile project center" application it is possible to add ArcGIS Online services as Base maps. Operational (editable) map layers can be a local mobile cache created with ArcGIS Desktop or can be created by adding an ArcGIS Server 10 service with the Mobile Data Access capability.

Here is a short video showing the Mobile project center that comes with ArcGIS Mobile:
http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/video/arcgis-mobile/details?entryID=86018768-1422-2418-8853-3213B5F47918

Comment: so how do I make use of the .wmpk file that mobile project center produces in my application?

Comment: You simply locate the .wmpk file in the file explorer and open by clicking it. It will then start the ArcGIS Mobile application and load the project. A folder will be created in the users AppData folder containing all the information the application needs to run. At this point the .wmpk file is not needed anymore, unless you want to change something in the project setup.

Comment: you are right - I guess I wasn't xplicit enough - I don't want to use the Mobile project center - I want to actually write an application that runs without it.  I was actually using the wrong classes and should have been using the MobileServiceConnection class